# Status per max TimeStamp

Tags: powerbi, dax

Lets assume i have a Power Bi table like :

```
CDI1 | 2023-06-08 09:00:00 | 2023-06-08 | A
CDI1 | 2023-06-08 14:45:00 | 2023-06-08 | A
CDI2 | 2023-06-08 10:30:00 | 2023-06-08 | A
CDI2 | 2023-06-08 13:15:00 | 2023-06-08 | A
CDI3 | 2023-06-08 11:20:00 | 2023-06-08 | B
CDI3 | 2023-06-08 16:30:00 | 2023-06-08 | A
CDI4 | 2023-06-08 12:05:00 | 2023-06-08 | A
CDI4 | 2023-06-08 15:45:00 | 2023-06-08 | A
CDI5 | 2023-06-08 13:50:00 | 2023-06-08 | A
CDI5 | 2023-06-08 17:00:00 | 2023-06-08 | B
```

How can i calculate with a dax measure the distinct cdis that are on each status but the business rule i only take the status of the max timestamp of each cdi

```
DistinctCDIByMaxStatus = 
VAR SelectedDate = SELECTEDVALUE('YourTable'[CreatedDate])
RETURN
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT('YourTable'[CDI]),
    FILTER(
        ALL('YourTable'),
        'YourTable'[CreatedDate] = SelectedDate &&
        'YourTable'[Status] =
            CALCULATE(
                MAX('YourTable'[Status]),
                ALLEXCEPT('YourTable', 'YourTable'[CDI])
            )
    )
)
```

Comment: I suggest you also provide an idea of exactly what result you are after. I think after a lot of interpretationg you are looking for something like `B = 1, A = 4`, but it's better if you are explicit about what you want the result to be.

Comment: correct.Let me descripe the business story behind the measure .I want to create a kpi for customer support department and at the end of each day i want to know how are the distinct customers that are stuck on each status.That the reason i only want to only tale into consideration the status of their max timestamp.How can i write a measure that gives me that results ?